# How to force stop a different Android service from my app?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

First of all, let me say that I know that is is bad practice, not good, probably not allowed (technically) etc, etc, etc... to force stop another service from my app.

However, there ARE some use cases to warrant this need. In my case, for example, there is a 3rd party service that is installed by my app because of my reference to it ("it" is a barcode scanning SDK). The SDK states that I must call method to something called

```
GetScannerService();
```

I have observed that this call will either start the service or grab the instance to it if it is already running.

Furthermore, there are some calls that have to be done during onStop and onDestroy of my app which effectively will stop this third party service.

All that said, I have seen cases where this service gets stuck in a weird state. I have no control over the code (and bugs) in this package. Yes, I have reached out to them but have been unsuccessful so far to get them to fix the root cause. When it is stuck in this state, I can see it in the list of running services (and sometimes it is listed in the cached ones) but when my app calls to GetScannerService, it throws an exception that basically states the service cannot be started...but it already is.

So, when this happens, if I manually to the running services list and find it (again, sometimes it is in cached) and click force stop, this will fix things and my app works as expected again...until it happens again that is.

So, I want and need to have my app control this service. The thought is on startup, when I do the first call to GetScannerService, if it returns the exception, I will basically force stop it so that I can then call again and have it started. In other words, I want to automate the force stop function.

I know technically this is not allowed but I have also read that there are ways to do it, even if you don't have root.

So far, I can get the list of all running services and I can see the service in question in my list. Which means I also have access to a lot of information about the running service. But, what I have tried does not work. I have tried to KillBackgroundProcesses but it did not work, the service is still in the list.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
   private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var am = (ActivityManager)this.Application.ApplicationContext.GetSystemService(Context.ActivityService);
        var taskList = am.GetRunningServices(serviceListLimit);

        List<string> serviceNames = new List<string>();


        foreach(var t in taskList)
        {
            serviceNames.Add(t.Service.PackageName);
        }

        var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, serviceNames);

        services.Adapter = adapter;

        if (serviceNames.Contains(emdkServiceName))
            testKillService(am, emdkClass);
    }



    private void testKillService(ActivityManager am, Class emdkClass)
    {
        am.KillBackgroundProcesses(emdkServiceName);
    }
```

So, I can list them and see it in the list as well as grab details about the item in the list. Anybody know how I can force stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Process](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html) class:

```
void killProcess (int pid)
```

You can get the "pid" from the [ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html).

Comment: Thank you for the response, I had a chance to try this today. It seems to work (ie no exceptions) but it does not actually kill the process, it is still in the list. I first got the pid as you mentioned and during the breakpoints, I can see that I do have the process I care about captured (I see class name, pid, etc..). I then call Android.OS.Process.KillProcess(pid); but it does not die!!! Note, there is a Java.Lang.Process but that is not the one. I also checked my permissions in my manifest. Unless I missed one, I think I got them all. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Actually, I am reading that Process.KillProcess will only kill the process if the UID of the process matches my UID. This may be the culprit. My SDK call does start this process but I cannot be sure that it does have the same UID as my app. This may be why Android OS (as a safety feature) does not actually kill it. However, I read too that if you specify the permission KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES, you can use ActivityManager.KillBackgroundProcesses(name) which I have done and it too is not working. Maybe I am not specifying the name properly?

Comment: I think the main problem here is the `START_STICKY` flag on those services.
If you check all your kill implementation, I think minimum one of those should kill the service. BUT because the service was started as a STICKY, the OS will restart it every time. You can check it in your `logcat`. AND if you check the PID of the "not" killed service (e.g. in console with the `top` command), it is not the same, what you killed previously.